# How would you create a reverse proxy using a Firebase function?

Tags: firebase, reverse-proxy

I'd like to create a reverse proxy for my analytics so that it doesn't get shut down by ad blockers.

Cloudflare has an excellent API for this using their web-workers but using them in conjuction with a CNAME (i.e. on your own host) is only available on their enterprise plan.

The cloudflare code to do the reverse proxy is simply:

```js
addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
    request = new Request(request)
    var url = new URL(request.url)
    url.hostname = 'api-js.mixpanel.com'
    return await fetch(url, request)
}
```

How might one go about creating the same type of functionality using a Firebase function instead?

Comment: When a function is invoked, won't it be invoked from GCP?  As such, the request will originate from Google.  Maybe a quick diagram to illustrate what you are trying to achieve may help?

Comment: Hi @Kolban. There's a good chance I don't know what I'm talking about... I'd never even written a firebase function before today. I was just hoping I could expose an endpoint which would act as a reverse proxy which I could then point a CNAME to. Feels like it may be a reach...

Comment: Hi Peter ... no problems my friend.  We'll figure it out.  I'm thinking that what you mean by reverse proxy here is an endpoint where when client applications wish to invoke a Cloud Function that they reach a single endpoint and the front end that receives the request sends it to Cloud Functions.  I think that's how it works out of the box.  When you create a Cloud Function, you are given an assigned URL by Google that can then be reached.  That endpoint is a "load balancer" that routes the request to Cloud Function servers automatically.

Comment: Hi @Kolban - that's close but I believe that's a forward proxy. The effect that I'm looking for is one that allows me to get browser restrictions that stop an HTTP request being sent to a tracking endpoint (like api.mixpanel.com). In order to do that I setup a script/function on a subdomain of my own domain (tracking.mydomain.com). On the back end that domain sends all of the original HTTP payload to api.mixpanel.com and then proxies the response back to the browser. Thereby sending the request but via my own domain. Does that make more sense? :)

Comment: Might this be what we want?  https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/target-proxies   ... if I get the notion, using a target proxy, you can send requests to it and it will route them onwards (even externally over the Internet).  Might a diagram aid us in the discussion?

Comment: Thanks @Kolban, I'll take a look at that. In the end the Cloudflare proxy actually seems to have don the trick. I think that even though it wasn't on my own domain, just the fact that it wasn't on a blacklisted domain (i.e. Mixpanel) enabled it to do the job - so I think that's got me to where I need to be. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are specifically trying to proxy MixPanel requests to avoid Ad Blockers then you can do this via 2 methods

1. You can use Cloudflare Zaraz + Cloudflare Worker
2. You can use their official proxy, that can be hosted in Cloud Run or DigitalOcean droplet: https://github.com/mixpanel/tracking-proxy

Comment: That’s actually exactly what I ended up doing. I’m still intrigued as to how I could do it using Firebase but the Cloudflare route was the way I went in the end. BTW, SO is much more rewarding to answers that include the detail rather than just the links. Part of that is that SO is designed to be around for decades but links tend to degrade